# webRTC compilation windows 7 64 bit

Tags: webrtc, windows-7-x64, ninja

I am trying to compile the webRTC code but I get the following error.
I am **not** trying with Visual Studio.

The error got is `<PATH>/src/buildtools/win/gn.exe` cannot start because of incompatibility of 64 bit windows version. The confusion is I am compiling on Windows 7 64 bit. The error is confusing to say the least.

Steps followed are :-

Unzipping the `depot_tools` from the chromium webpage and setting up the correct path.

Then for downloading the webRTC and compilation the steps were

```
mkdir webrtc-checkout
cd webrtc-checkout
fetch --nohooks webrtc
gclient sync
```

`gn gen out/Default` < ***The problem arises here*** >

Answer (score 0):

We would need the entire trace of all the python script to give you a full answer, but it is *VERY* likely that you need to have MSVC 2015 (14) installed and to set the corresponding environment variable DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0. The scripts will otherwise stop working with cryptic error messages, even before the compilation. It fits your "symptoms".

See this for more answers (chromium and webrtc build instructions are shared):
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

If you copy paste the trace form the python scripts here, I might be able to help you more.